# Пагинация на wp не отрабатывает должным образом

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть страница автора, на ней выводиться информация об авторе плюс все его статьи.
Сделана пагинация, но она не отрабатывает как нужно.

```
<?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    ?>
    <?php
    $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $qury = query_posts(array ('paged' => $page,
        'post_type' => 'articles',
        'author' => $curauth->id,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ));
    if(have_posts()){ while(have_posts()){ the_post();
        wp_blog_pagination();
    }}
    else echo '';
    ?>
```

Сама пагинация выводиться, но переходишь на вторую страницу и выдает 404 ошибку.

Ответ:

```
function author_cpt_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_author()) {
            $query->set('post_type', array('articles'));
            $query->set('post_per_page', 6);
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','author_cpt_filter');
```

Comment: Не используйте вы `query_posts` она не для этого - https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/query-posts/

Comment: Уже разобрался, нашел решение. Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Замените `query_posts` на `new WP_Query` или `get_posts`:

```
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array (
    'paged' => $page,
    'post_type' => 'articles',
    'author' => $curauth->id,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        wp_blog_pagination();
    }
} else {
    echo '';
}
```